# Update command only updates first row vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, vba

I'm trying to update a database through a datagridview but the problem I'm having is that it only updates the first row in the datagridview. Any insight will be grateful, thanks.

```
    Dim Connection As New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)


    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("SendTable")
    Dim row As DataRow
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Attendance", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    For i = 0 To ClassRegisterdgv.Rows.Count - 1
        ' If ClassRegisterdgv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.Equals("") Then ClassRegisterdgv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.Equals("Present")
        Dim ID As Integer = ClassRegisterdgv.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        Dim Attendance As String = ClassRegisterdgv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
        row = dt.Rows.Add
        row.Item("ID") = ID
        row.Item("Attendance") = Attendance
    Next
    If Connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Connection.Open()
    End If
    Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE PupilInfo SET " & NewColumnCreated & " = @Attendance WHERE ID = @ID"
    Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand

    For Each newrow As DataRow In dt.Rows
        'For i = 0 To ClassRegisterdgv.Rows.Count - 1
        With sqlcommand
            .CommandText = sqlquery
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attendance", newrow.Item(1))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", newrow.Item(0))
            .Connection = Connection
            MessageBox.Show(newrow.Item(1) & newrow.Item(0))
            .ExecuteNonQuery()

        End With
    Next

    Connection.Close()
    ClassRegisterdgv.DataSource = Nothing
    dt.Clear()
```

Comment: Looks like your ".Add" logic uses the same "ID" for everything? Maybe DIM it outside the loop, then set value inside the loop?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn thanks for your help but I managed to fix it

Answer (score 2):

Only updates the first row because the parameters collection of the command object has not been cleaned. Try to do the following:

```
With sqlcommand
    .CommandText = sqlquery

    .Parameters.Clear()   '<─────── Insert this line in your code.

    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attendance", newrow.Item(1))
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", newrow.Item(0))
    .Connection = Connection
    MessageBox.Show(newrow.Item(1) & newrow.Item(0))
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```